# Is General Exception handling not so bad in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-4.0

In the code below I try to send a set of notifications and I want to know if a notification was sent successfully (to put it in a database later so never send it again).

Is it bad I'm catching `Exception` here? I really don't care about the reason a notification wasn't sent.

```
private static async Task<List<Tuple<NotificationToSend, bool>>> SendNotificationsAsync(IEnumerable<NotificationToSend> notificationsToSend)
{
    var tuples = new List<Tuple<NotificationToSend, bool>>();

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        foreach (var notification in notificationsToSend)
        {
            bool sentSuccessfully;

            try
            {
                var mailMessage = new MailMessage
                {
                    Subject = notification.Subject,
                    Body = $"{notification.Text} <br /> This notification was sent automatically",
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                };

                mailMessage.To.Add(notification.ToEmail);

                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
                sentSuccessfully = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                sentSuccessfully = false;
                // Here I also plan to log the exception
            }

            var tuple = new Tuple<NotificationToSend, bool>(notification, sentSuccessfully);
            tuples.Add(tuple);
        }
    }

    return tuples;
}
```

Comment: "Is this really so bad" is pretty opinion-based, isn´t it? Making it imposible to post a "right" or "whrong" answer here.

Comment: Your `try` block can be smaller, though - you only need it for `await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);` and `sentSuccessfully = true;`

Comment: @ZoharPeled what if the `notification` is null?

Comment: Do you really want to catch a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Not really. I don't want to catch anything. I just want to see if a notification was sent successfully.

Comment: Do you expect it to be null as a normal part of the flow?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Nope. Well, basically you are right. The only thing I should wrap in `try {} catch {}` is `await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);`

Comment: @ZoharPeled What if `mailMessage.To.Add()` will throw an exception by the way? If an email address is wrong or something.

Comment: Yes, that could happen, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `catch(Exception e)`, you should only catch exceptions that you know can be thrown. And with the SmtpClient [the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?view=netframework-4.8) says that one of the following four exceptions can be thrown:

- [ArgumentNullException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=netframework-4.8)
- [InvalidOperationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=netframework-4.8)
- [ObjectDisposedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.objectdisposedexception?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SmtpException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpexception?view=netframework-4.8)

So you should do it like this:

```cs
var sentSuccessfully = false;

var mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    Subject = notification.Subject,
    Body = $"{notification.Text} <br /> This notification was sent automatically",
    IsBodyHtml = true
};

MailMessage.To.Add(notification.ToEmail);

try
{
    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
    sentSuccessfully = true;
}
catch (ArgumentNullException e)
{
    sentSuccessfully = false;
    // Handle Argument Exception
}
catch (InvalidOperationException e)
{
    sentSuccessfully = false;
    // Handle InvalidOperation Exception
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
{
    // This one shouldn't happen, so you could leave it out
    sentSuccessfully = false;
    // Do Handle ObjectDisposed Exception
}
catch (SmtpException e)
{
    sentSuccessfully = false;
    // Handle Smtp Exception
}
```

The reason for this is much better logging, if you know the exception that was thrown the log could display something like 'ArgumentNullException was thrown, *insert a possible explanation as to why*'

Or if you want to handle all exceptions the same way:

```cs
try
{
    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
    sentSuccessfully = true;
}
catch (Exception e) when (e is ArgumentNullException || 
    e is InvalidOperationException || 
    e is ObjectDisposedException || 
    e is SmtpException)
{
    sentSuccessfully = false;
    // Handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what behavior you want to achieve.
Blanket catch like this will make program "limp" even if someone introduces a blunt error like null reference inside try...catch. Usually this is not desired and it's better to fail fast.

If you want program to carry on only after 'expected' SMTP infrastructural error then catch only specific types of exceptions (e.g. SmtpException or whatever can be thrown by SendMailAsync) and otherwise let the exception to bubble up.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd go for:

```
private static async Task<List<Tuple<NotificationToSend, bool>>> SendNotificationsAsync(IEnumerable<NotificationToSend> notificationsToSend)
{
    var tuples = new List<Tuple<NotificationToSend, bool>>();

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        foreach (var notification in notificationsToSend)
        {
            bool sentSuccessfully = SendNotificationAsync(smtpClient, notification);

            var tuple = new Tuple<NotificationToSend, bool>(notification, sentSuccessfully);
            tuples.Add(tuple);
        }
    }

    return tuples;
}

private static async Task<bool> SendNotificationAsync(SmtpClient smtpClient, NotificationToSend notification)
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
        Subject = notification.Subject,
        Body = $"{notification.Text} <br /> This notification was sent automatically",
        IsBodyHtml = true
    };

    mailMessage.To.Add(notification.ToEmail);

    try
    {
        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Here I also plan to log the exception
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you treat a notification sent successfully from the start?

Comment: check the edit.

Comment: Now you should also sure `smtpClient` is in an appropriate and ready state in `SendNotificationAsync` to send emails, don't you?

Comment: Not really... besides, if it isn't configured properly, you get the list with the boolean set to false for all... I thought that's what you wanted, no?

Comment: Also, what if a string passed to `mailMessage.To.Add()` is wrong and not an email address at all? The notification will not be sent.

Comment: What is the type of the property `ToEmail`? If it's already of the type `MailAddress`, then you don't need to worry.

Comment: It's just `string`

Comment: Then you need to test it. I'm not sure if it'd throw an exception on `Add` or on `SendMailAsync`.

Comment: Actually, my question was about greedy exception handling in this case. Do you thing this is appropriate here?

Comment: Yes, I think so.