# How do I ensure an operation won't crash the whole app?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, crash

I have an application performing some additional jobs like cleaning old logs, sending notifications and so on. If one job fails I don't want the whole application to stop working and not perform jobs what left.

So for example,

```
await SendUsersBirthdayEmailsAsync(); // <-- if something fails while trying to send birthday emails here, I don't want the app to stop working and not clean logs and so on...
await DeleteOutdatedLogsAsync();
await SendSystemNotificationsAsync();
```

What would you recommend me to go with?

Comment: Why not use try catch...

Comment: What kind of app is this (console/wpf/winforms/...)? What do you mean by 'crash the whole app'? What would you like to do if something fails in the birthday mail logic?

Comment: @42LeapsOfFaith Do you mean just to catch general Exception like `try { ... } catch { ... }`?

Comment: @Fortega It's a console application run by Windows Task Scheduler every night. If something fails in birthday mailing, I just want to log it and then let the app go further with its left tasks.

Comment: @kseen Yes, use try { ... } catch { ... }

Comment: The problem is, when you don't know what failures might occur, you have no way of knowing *whether the program is still in a fit state to execute any further actions*. Don't try to soldier on "no matter what". Catch/handle the errors you can reasonably *expect* and *handle* and otherwise the most sensible thing to do is to allow the program to crash and burn. Unless you're writing a safety critical system, in which case you won't be using C# anyway.

Comment: @kseen Please close your question by accepting any of the provided answers if it answers your question.

Answer (score 8):

Use `try-catch` block on every part of the code that can fail.
Depending on what you need, use `try-catch-finally` block.

On every `catch` block, log the exception however you want. I use Nlog for logging so i suggest looking into that.

```
try{
    //do work here
}
catch(Exception e){
    //log exception here
}
//optional
finally{
    //do optional needed work here
}
```

Something like this:

```
public bool SendUsersBirthdayEmailsAsync(){
    try{
        SendMail();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        LogException(e);
    }
    //optional
    finally{
        OptionalWork();
    }       
}
```

EDIT: About avoiding using generic exception

You can always use multiple `catch` blocks any define different behavior for each type of exception. This is useful when you know what kind of exception can be expected.
Example:

```
public bool SendUsersBirthdayEmailsAsync(){
    try{
        SendMail();
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException tae)
    {
        LogException(tae);
        //do something specific
    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException tie)
    {
        LogException(tie);
        //do something specific
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        LogException(e);
    }
    //optional
    finally{
        OptionalWork();
    }       
}
```

EDIT 2: [Official Microsoft guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions) for exception handling.

> Use `try/catch` blocks around code that can potentially generate an exception and your code can recover from that exception. In `catch` blocks, always order exceptions from the most derived to the least derived. All exceptions derive from `Exception`. More derived exceptions are not handled by a `catch` clause that is preceded by a `catch` clause for a base exception class. When your code cannot recover from an exception, don't catch that exception. Enable methods further up the call stack to recover if possible.
>
> Clean up resources allocated with either `using` statements, or `finally` blocks. Prefer `using` statements to automatically clean up resources when exceptions are thrown. Use `finally` blocks to clean up resources that don't implement `IDisposable`. Code in a `finally` clause is almost always executed even when exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Is there any chance we can avoid using generic exception handling along with trying to have it the most fault-tolerant? I've asked about the way you do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588098/is-general-exception-handling-not-so-bad-in-this-case

Comment: It depends on the action you are executing. If you are using threads for example, you can use   catch (ThreadInterruptedException). Using generic exception handling is the safest way for your program to not explode and to be able to recover.

Comment: You could try starting each task on a different thread and use the original thread as a watchdog.

Comment: @kseen Please, check my edit in the answer, if that is what you meant.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the clarifying. But no, in this case, I don't know what exceptions exactly might occur. Is there any way to not use generic exception handling but with the safety of it? :)

Comment: As far as I know, catching generic exception is the safest way to prevent your app from crash&burn scenario. But again, depending on your code functionality, maybe some other mechanisms could be implemented, but it's hard to say without seeing the code first.

Comment: Also, take a look at the link I've just put in the Edit2 in the answer, maybe it helps you to find something useful :)

Comment: @kseen Is there anything else you want to know about this solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
Task<Task> task = (SendUsersBirthdayEmailsAsync()
            .ContinueWith(x => Task.WhenAll(DeleteOutdatedLogsAsync(), SendSystemNotificationsAsync())));
await await task;
```

For more general sample the below code provided:

```
class TaskTest
{
    public async void Start()
    {

        await (
            (await One().ContinueWith(x => Task.WhenAll(Two(), Three())))
            .ContinueWith(x=> Four()));
    }

    private async Task One()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        throw new Exception();
    }

    private async Task Two()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        throw new Exception();

    }
    private async Task Three()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        throw new Exception();
    }

    private async Task Four()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("4");
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

running this code shows that throwing exceptions inside tasks does not halt the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already doing it with a scheduler why not separate it into smaller tasks? In that way if one action fails it will not bring down all the others. Also it is a good practice to have many smaller applications with dedicated responsibilities rather than a generic one that does everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a reliable option to ensure the process is completed and is traceable, you can go with [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). You can put your retry logic in case of failures by handling exceptions also.

Answer (score 0):

Since the name of the methods suggests, that these methods are independent of each other, just make sure each returns an await-able task and put them into a list. Your use of `await` suggests, they already do.

Put one try-catch around it and catch the AggregateExeption.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
try
{
  tasks.Add(SendUsersBirthdayEmailsAsync());
  tasks.Add(DeleteOutdatedLogsAsync());
  tasks.Add(SendSystemNotificationsAsync());

  Task.WhenAll(tasks); // waits for all tasks to finish
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   //Log e.ToString(); will give you all inner exceptions of the aggregate exception as well, incl. StackTraces, so expect possibly a lot of chars, wherever you log it.
}
```

This may also speed things up, because they are now running in parallel. But since they all seem to work on a database (most likely the same), it might not be much, if at all, because of the scheduling overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your methods using the [Try-Pattern](https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/the-trycan-pattern/) and have them return Boolean.
Let every method handle exceptions on it's own so that you are sure no unhandled exceptions can be thrown to kill off your application.

In case a failure will result in unrecoverable program state, the methods should return false and your application should quit in a clean way by itself.

Answer (score 0):

### Unobserved Task Exceptions

> ```
> await SendUsersBirthdayEmailsAsync(); // uses TaskScheduler
> ```

Since you are working with a TaskScheduler, check out [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.8).

> Occurs when a faulted task's unobserved exception is about to trigger
>   exception escalation policy, which, **by default, would terminate the
>   process**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Try-Catch in every function as follow.

```
try{
    //write your code
}
catch(Exception e){
    //your exception will be here
}
```

You can generate a log file for that exception. 
Just Do one thing for your log File. Create A Log Class and a log file generate function.
call that function in catch area of your all functions.

Let you create a Log class with name **clsLog**. and a static function with name **InsertLog(string exception, string functionname)**.

Use this log method in your all function as follow.

```
public void insertcity()
{
 try
 {
   //Insert city programming
 }
 catch (exception ex)
 {
   clsLog.InsertLog(ex.Message,"insertCity");
   //do something else you want.
 }        
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590877/how-do-i-ensure-an-operation-wont-crash-the-whole-app#57796513) that [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4016498/andreas)  used - fits what I was thinking - however I would make one more piece - A Cancellation Token - with a time limit on how long you would think is enough time - so that everything completes.

The individual tasks in the Wait means that they all come back together at that point while they execute seperately. You can catch the agreggate exceptions if they occur - and then determine if it was timeout - or something you need to log.

The Two suggestions on UnhandledException and UnhandledTask Exception SHOULD be included also - for what ever reason that they stop..

I would also think about making this a Windows service so that you can pass the cancellation token into the tasks from startup - and have a timer on when the service actually runs - instead of a scheduled task - then with all the exception handling you can see what the log tells you over time - which feels a little more resilient than a console app to me - but that is how we normally run tasks in this vein.

You can start and stop a service like this in a console app for testing - and then hand it off into a project that handles the OnStart and OnStop events - passing the Cancellation token in - OnStop would cancel the token and stop the service loops.

Answer (score 0):

i think if u use

```
try{
    //your nice work
}
catch(Exception e){
    //hmm.. error ok i will show u
}
//optional
finally{
    //again start the operation if u failed here.
}
```

i also make the same application in which when some error comes and failed then in the catch exception i make the log in system and also again restart the application in the finally. so it will never die.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to found out what exception you getting from `async` to actually get this exception and understand it you can use on a main `Thread`:

```
MyTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This will allow you to see the text of the actual exception that you have on your `await` Thread.

---

And a little bit if you don't want a main Thread to return to the line with `await` you also can use:

```
await SendUsersBirthdayEmailsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This will just continue your Task on the nearest free Thread.

But need to say this will cause an exception on Android because it have some restrictions of using Threads.

---

In the case you don't want to waste your time or don't need to handle the exception manually and fixing it `try`, `catch` `finally` is always an option.